# How to plot intervals from a Pandas DataFrame using pyplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a DataFrame that logs hours based on Employee:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Jack', 0, 6], ['Jack', 8, 12],['Barry', 0, 5], ['Barry', 7, 15]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Employee', 'Start', 'End'])

  Employee  Start  End
0     Jack      0    6
1     Jack      8   12
2    Barry      0    5
3    Barry      7   15
```

How can I plot out the work intervals where the x axis is time and the y axis is for the employee key using pyplot?
To arrive at something like this where the bars are numbered with start/end times.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a for loop:

```
for _, r in df.iterrows():
    plt.plot(r[['Start','End']], [r['Employee'],r['Employee']], color='blue')
    plt.annotate(f"{r['Start']}",(r['Start'], r['Employee']), va='bottom')
    plt.annotate(f"{r['End']}",(r['End'], r['Employee']), va='bottom', ha='center')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks! that did it. if i wanted to handle multiple bars per employee stacked on top of each other (say one for RestStart/RestEnd, how would I offset the bars so they don't fall on top of one another? here's what I have so far: https://ibb.co/d6srF7Q   you can see the orange bar for 'Rest' is overlapping. https://pastebin.com/pMtTKn6p